# How to print a file to stdout?

Tags: python

I've searched and I can only find questions about the other way around: writing stdin to a file.

Is there a quick and easy way to dump the contents of a file to `stdout`?

Comment: you can plugin my function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/how-to-print-a-file-to-stdout/73336009#73336009

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Sure. Assuming you have a string with the file's name called `fname`, the following does the trick.

```
with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
    print(fin.read())
```

Comment: Note that this will add an extra newline at the end of the output.

Comment: For both Python 3 compatibility _and_ avoiding the trailing newline, the last line should probably read: `print(fin.read(), end="")`. To leverage that solution under Python 2, a prefixing `from __future__ import print_function` will be needed. Of course, Python 2 applications should _always_ use the Python 3 `print()` function anyway – so that isn't much of a burden.

Answer (score 45):

If it's a large file and you don't want to consume a ton of memory as might happen with Ben's solution, the extra code in

```
>>> import shutil
>>> import sys
>>> with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
...    shutil.copyfileobj(f, sys.stdout)
```

also works.

Answer (score 18):

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

From http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most size bytes are read and returned. If the end of the file has been reached, f.read() will return an empty string ("").

Answer (score 10):

My shortened version in Python3

```
print(open('file.txt').read())
```

Comment: Note: this does not close the file.

Answer (score 3):

you can also try this

`print ''.join(file('example.txt'))`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this with the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, you can use [`pathlib.Path.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) to open the file and print the text from `read()`:

```
from pathlib import Path

fpath = Path("somefile.txt")

with fpath.open() as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Or simply call [`pathlib.Path.read_text()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text):

```
from pathlib import Path

fpath = Path("somefile.txt")

print(fpath.read_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
txt = <file_path>
txt_opn = open(txt)
print txt_opn.read()
```

This will give you file output.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on @bgporter's answer, with Python-3 you will probably want to operate on bytes instead of needlessly converting things to utf-8:

```
>>> import shutil
>>> import sys
>>> with open("test.txt", "rb") as f:
...    shutil.copyfileobj(f, sys.stdout.buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `jupyter notebook`, you can simply use:

```
!cat /path/to/filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Operating on the file's line iterator (if you open in text mode -- the default) is simple and memory-efficient:

```py
with open(path, mode="rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end="")
```

Note the `end=""` because the lines will include their line-ending char(s).

This is almost exactly one of the examples in the docs linked at (other) Ben's answer: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
def expanduser(path: Union[str, Path]):
    """

    note: if you give in a path no need to get the output of this function because it mutates path. If you
    give a string you do need to assign the output to a new variable
    :param path:
    :return:
    """
    if not isinstance(path, Path):
        # path: Path = Path(path).expanduser()
        path: Path = Path(path).expanduser()
    path = path.expanduser()
    assert not '~' in str(path), f'Path username was not expanded properly see path: {path=}'
    return path

def cat_file(path2filename: Union[str, Path]):
    """prints/displays file contents. Do path / filename or the like outside of this function. ~ is alright to use. """
    path2filename = expanduser(path2filename)
    with open(path2filename, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

or install my ultimate-utils library from pypi.