# How do I print the content of a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm very new to programming (obviously) and really advanced computer stuff in general. I've only have basic computer knowledge, so I decided I wanted to learn more. Thus I'm teaching myself (through videos and ebooks) how to program.

Anyways, I'm working on a piece of code that will open a file, print out the contents on the screen, ask you if you want to edit/delete/etc the contents, do it, and then re-print out the results and ask you for confirmation to save.

I'm stuck at the printing the contents of the file. I don't know what command to use to do this. I've tried typing in several commands previously but here is the latest I've tried and no the code isn't complete:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
print "Who are you?"
name = raw_input()

print "What file are you looking for today?"
file = raw_input()

print (file)

print "Ok then, here's the file you wanted." 

print "Would you like to delete the contents? Yes or No?"
```

I'm trying to write these practice codes to include as much as I've learned thus far. Also I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04 and Python 2.7.4 if that makes any difference. Thanks for any help thus far :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a file to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/how-to-print-a-file-to-stdout)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Opening a file in python for reading is easy:

```
f = open('example.txt', 'r')
```

To get everything in the file, just use read()

```
file_contents = f.read()
```

And to print the contents, just do:

```
print (file_contents)
```

Don't forget to close the file when you're done.

```
f.close()
```

Comment: You should use the with clause, as others have mentioned in solutions below, as the context manager will take care of closing the file.

Answer (score 50):

Just do this:

```
>>> with open("path/to/file") as f: # The with keyword automatically closes the file when you are done
...     print f.read()
```

This will print the file in the terminal.

Comment: Because it is more Pythonic ;-)

Comment: It seems in newer versions of Python it should be `print(f.read())`

Answer (score 5):

```
with open("filename.txt", "w+") as file:
  for line in file:
    print line
```

This `with` statement automatically opens and closes it for you and you can iterate over the lines of the file with a simple `for` loop

Answer (score 4):

## How to read and print the content of a txt file

Assume you got a file called file.txt that you want to read in a program and the content is this:

```
this is the content of the file
with open you can read it and
then with a loop you can print it
on the screen. Using enconding='utf-8'
you avoid some strange convertions of
caracters. With strip(), you avoid printing
an empty line between each (not empty) line
```

You can read this content: write the following script in notepad:

```
with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip())
```

save it as readfile.py for example, in the same folder of the txt file.

Then you run it (shift + right click of the mouse and select the prompt from the contextual menu) writing in the prompt:

C:\examples> python readfile.py

You should get this. Play attention to the word, they have to be written just as you see them and to the indentation. It is important in python. Use always the same indentation in each file (4 spaces are good).

> output

```
this is the content of the file
with open you can read it and
then with a loop you can print it
on the screen. Using enconding='utf-8'
you avoid some strange convertions of
caracters. With strip(), you avoid printing
an empty line between each (not empty) line
```

Answer (score 3):

to input a file:

```
fin = open(filename) #filename should be a string type: e.g filename = 'file.txt'
```

to output this file you can do:

```
for element in fin:
    print element
```

if the elements are a string you'd better add this before print:

```
element = element.strip()
```

`strip()` remove notations like this: `/n`

Comment: after opening a file, you can print everything by this as well:


    `print fin`

Comment: I've formatted your post slightly - you might also want to change `/n` to be `\n`...

Answer (score 2):

`print ''.join(file('example.txt'))`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the contents of a file separated, line-by-line in a list:

```
with open('xyz.txt') as f_obj:
    f_obj.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple

```
#Opening file
f= open('sample.txt')
#reading everything in file
r=f.read()
#reading at particular index
r=f.read(1)
#print
print(r)
```

Presenting snapshot from my visual studio IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

single line to read/print contents of a file

**reading file : example.txt**

```
 print(open('example.txt', 'r').read())
```

*output:*

> u r reading the contents of example.txt file

Answer (score 0):

**Reading and printing the content of a text file `(.txt)` in Python3**

Consider this as the content of text file with the name `world.txt`:

```
Hello World! This is an example of Content of the Text file we are about to read and print
using python!
```

First we will open this file by doing this:

```
file= open("world.txt", 'r')
```

Now we will get the *content* of file in a variable using `.read()` like this:

```
content_of_file= file.read()
```

Finally we will just print the `content_of_file` variable using `print` command.

```
print(content_of_file)
```

**Output**:

> Hello World! This is an example of Content of the Text file we are about to read and print
> using python!