# Print all files in the sub-folders of a folder

Tags: python, file-management, utility

I'm planning on using Robobasket to organise my folders like this,

Invoices
- Jan/Feb/Mar
- Customer Number 1/Customer Number 2
- Then the dates the invoices actual arrived on

The files are named, Month/Customer Number/Date.

What I need to be able to do is, right click on the month, and have it print all the invoice for that month. Specifically printed out by Customer Number 1, then all the dates in order, say 3rd, 17th, 31st, then Customer Number 2, 12thst 22nd, etc.

I have several thousand invoices a month, so you can see why manually printing, even just by Customer number is not something I can do.

The system is running Windows 7, although any programs which can work with a server would be great too, as it's entirely possible, that'll happen soon.

I have basic script skills in C, Python, and Forthe; But am willing to learn for the sake of this issue.

The important thing is that someone who has very little computer skills can at the end of this set it going. Hence the desire for it to be accessible through the context menu.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do multiple things to get that working.

1. You need a Python environment installed on the machine or you have to pack your script as an executable. Use `py2exe` for this.
2. To get all the files in a given directory, you could use the `glob` module from python, if you need to filter. Or you could use the approach from denis.
3. You have to add a context menu item via the registry or using a context menu editor. Look [there](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors) for an instruction.
4. Ideally, you pack everything into an installer to distribute the stuff. Including a batch script that adds the context menu item to the registry.

Comment: So if I had the glob module check, glob.glob('C:\Users\user\Desktop\Invoice\Month\*'), and had Month as a variable to be defined as the folder I'm right clicking, would that work?

Comment: That should do the trick. However, I recommend 'os.listdir(path)' when you want to print everything inside the path-folder. It should be faster as glob, since glob does a call to 'os.listdir()', too. By clicking right on the folder, you have to catch the folder path and provide it as path-variable.

Comment: Would that include the the folders lower on the directory?
I.e. if I did the month, it would grab all the invoices in all the "Customer Number" folders, for that month?
Sorry, for being pedantic, but I'm gonna have to idiot proof it for the boss.

Comment: Now it becomes tricky. IMHO, `os.listdir` just lists the contents of the directory w/o drilling into sub-directories. For that, you have to use `os.walk` (< Python 3.5) or `glob.glob` (Python 3.5, with new functionality for sub-directories).

Comment: So glob.glob(path), with the folder I right click on being caught and provided as path-variable will do the trick or do I need to look into glob further to get it to do the sub-directories?

Comment: Python 3.5: `glob.glob(path + "\**\*.csv", recursive=True)` should give you all csv-files in the given path and its subdirectories. see [glob documentation Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Comment: Thanks man, you're a lifesaver.
This'll speed up my project, so much.
You have a good day, mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get all the files in current directory:

```
import os

files = os.listdir(os.curdir)
```

Now you have all the files in `files` variable. In order to print contents of all the files in current directory, you can follow this post
[How do I print the content of a .txt file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256363/how-do-i-print-the-content-of-a-txt-file-in-python)