# How do get Python to print the contents of a file

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm trying to get Python to print the contents of a file:

```
log = open("/path/to/my/file.txt", "r")
print str(log)
```

Gives me the output:

```
<open file '/path/to/my/file.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7fd37f969390>
```

Instead of printing the file. The file just has one short string of text in it, and when I do the opposite (writing the user_input from my Python script to that same file) it works properly.

edit: I see what Python thinks I'm asking it, I'm just wondering what the command to print something from inside a file is.

Comment: Try reading the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), maybe?

Comment: `print(open('/path/to/file'[, "r"]).read())`

Comment: you can plugin my function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/how-to-print-a-file-to-stdout/73336009#73336009

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`open` gives you an iterator that doesn't automatically load the whole file at once. It iterates by line so you can write a loop like so:

```
for line in log:
    print(line)
```

If all you want to do is print the contents of the file to screen, you can use `print(log.read())`

Answer (score 67):

It is better to handle this with "with" to close the descriptor automatically for you. This will work with both 2.7 and python 3.

```
with open('/path/to/my/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: you can plugin my function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/how-to-print-a-file-to-stdout/73336009#73336009

Answer (score 9):

`open()` will actually open a [file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) for you to read.  If your intention is to read the complete contents of the file into the log variable then you should use `read()`

```
log = open("/path/to/my/file.txt", "r").read()
print(log)
```

The above code will print out the contents of the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
file_o=open("/path/to/my/file.txt")   //creates an object file_o to access the file
content=file_o.read()                 //file is read using the created object
print(content)                        //print-out the contents of file
file_o.close()
```