# How to print contents on file to console in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print a text file containing 4x4 grid of numbers to the console but my code isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
  def Viewfile(self):
    try:
        viewFileOpen=open(self.viewFileName,'r')
        for viewLine in viewFileOpen:
            self.theViewBoard.append(viewLine)
        print self.theViewBoard
        '''
```

I have tried with and without split here

```
        viewFileOpen=open(self.viewFileName,'r')
        for viewLine in viewFileOpen:
            viewListofValues=viewLine.split()
            viewRow=[]

            for viewItem in viewListofValues:
                viewRow.append(viewItem)
            self.theViewBoard.append(viewRow)
        print self.theViewBoard'''
    except:
        print"Some Error In getting the file printed at the end"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a file to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/how-to-print-a-file-to-stdout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just read the file and print that to the console like this:

```
def Viewfile(self):
    with open(self.viewFileName,'r') as viewFileOpen:
        data = viewFileOpen.read()
    print(data)
```

Comment: my file consist of 4x4 grids of numbers it ain't going through the file yet !!

Comment: What do you mean, "it ain't going through the file yet"

Comment: @Smple_V Can you post the content of your file and exactly how you are looking to display it?

Comment: its not reading the file yet, one more question tho, i have fileA(contaning conde) and fileB(text file) in same folder, i am passing argument as "nameOfTextFile.txt" is it ok

Comment: @Igor its a file with values like in a 4x4 matrix i just want to display the matrix

Comment: So you want to display an empty grid that you plan to populate in the future?

Comment: @Igor sorry for the confusion I have a populate field of 4x4 integer matrix in the text file, which I want to display in the console