# Python 3.6 printing out the text in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.6

Basically I want my python code to be able to read the line I have in my .txt file and print it out in another file when called.

What I have tried:

```
var = open("Test.txt")
print(var)
```

I have also tried using readlines():

```
var = open("Test.txt")
abcd = var.readlines()
print(abcd)
```

And what I get when I use that:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Test.txt' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>
```

Comment: You need to fix your question to properly display your code block.

Comment: the result of abcd should be a list of strings. The TextIOWrapper is the the value of var. Please check out the docs for more info on TextIO https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase

Comment: You would normally use `var = open("Test.txt").readlines()` then `print(var[0])` to print the first line.  The stack trace you posted is incomplete.   If you post the rest you are more likely to get help.  Here is the documentation for `readlines()` https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a file to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/how-to-print-a-file-to-stdout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a context manager, what does this get you?

```
with open('Test.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

print (content)
```

Comment: File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Either something is wrong with your file or you need to reinstall Python and try again.

Comment: Thanks you answer worked! Re-installed python and got rid of the error. Thanks heaps!

Comment: @INeedHelpAndFast No problem

Answer (score 3):

What you are printing is only the object reference of the file and not the actual text within it. When printing out the content of a file in python you must use the `read()` function to return the content of the file. You should also specify the actions you want to take with the file in the `open()` function.

- `r` is read
- `w` is write
- `r+` is read and write

For your situation you would use:

```
    var = open('Test.txt', 'r')
    content = var.read()
    print(content)
```

This would return the entire content of the file.