# Printing out a text file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, formatting, output

I am making a Quiz. When I try to print the results which are stored in a file, this is the output:

Instead of actually creating new lines when there is a '\n' it prints the '\n' instead.

> ['\n', 'Username:\n', 'Tes123\n', 'Subject:\n', 'Computer Science\n',
>   'Difficulty:\n', 'Hard\n', 'Score:\n', '5\n', 'Grade:\n', 'A\n']

In the text file the results are presented like this. **This is what I want the output to look like:**

[image]

This is my code to read the data from this text file and then print it into the interpreter.

```
with open(leaderboarddetails) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    print("Here are all the current results:")
    print('\n')
    print(data)
```

Comment: `data` is a list. When you print it will print entire list

Comment: You can think of it in the following way: When you print `data` you are trying to display the value of it as a string. In your case the value is a collection of `string` elements. Each of the strings contains the `\n` character. If you want the `\n` character to be read as an escape sequence and cause a line feed, you have to pass the string itself as an argument to the print function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple and efficient way to read data in from a file and creating a new lines.

```
for line in f:
 print(line, end='')
```

This reads the data into new lines every time it reaches the end of the sentence or line. For more information see [Input / Output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for python.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this instead:

```
with open(leaderboarddetails) as f:
data = f.readlines()
print("Here are all the current results:")
print('\n')
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

p.s
it might be better for you not to save \n in the file at all and just do this:

```
with open(leaderboarddetails) as f:
data = f.readlines()
print("Here are all the current results:")
print('\n')
for item in data:
    print("\n"+str(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to iter on your data.

How about this?

```
with open(leaderboarddetails) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    print("Here are all the current results:")
    print('\n')
    for info in data:
        print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try these after your print method

```
for line in data:
    print(line, end='')
print('-'*10)
print(''.join(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of '\n' is [os.linesep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).
[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/python-printing-a-file-to-stdout) helped me with printing the file if that is what you need.

```
with open(leaderboarddetails,'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```