# How to use SSH key pair without saving private key with paramiko python

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I would like to know whether it is possible to use SSH key pair without saving private key file permanently anywhere (it is not possible to use user/password authentication). After generating it (to the temp folder) with:

```
from paramiko import RSAKey
bits = 2048
filename='output'
#Private key
prv = RSAKey.generate(bits=bits)
prv.write_private_key_file(filename, password='')

#Public key
pub = RSAKey(filename=filename, password='')
with open("%s.pub" % filename, "w") as f:
    f.write("%s %s" % (pub.get_name(), pub.get_base64()))
```

Can one provide the public key to the remove server owner to add it to his known keys and then while attempting to join to his server use some kind of mechanism that does not require having private key stored permanently anywhere?

Thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, could you please provide an example? Assume the public key is obtained as pub.get_base64(). It should be provided to the host but from_private_key_file() method used to return correct object that can be passed as a pkey argument to connect() method will not accept any hardcoded piece?

Comment: What is the way of converting my private key ('prv' in the example above) to string that can be used as in the post you mentioned above. I only found out this method: pub.get_base64() that can be used for public keys. Thanks

Comment: `prv.write_private_key_file` gets you the key in that format (if you remove the `password` argument).

Comment: if I do prv = RSAKey.generate(bits=bits) and then prv.write_private_key_file(filename) and then print prv, it returns something (Ï¸ˆWNµ?Þgñè™ž...) that cannot be inserted into the write() method. If I do prv.get_base64() it returns the same as pub.get_base()?

Comment: The **contents of the file** created with `write_private_key_file` is what you need.

Comment: I understand but I am newb in this area, I do not know how to access the contents of the file (prv). My aim is to print the contents so that I can copy it and paste it afterwards. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for this - [Python: printing a file to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8084260/850848)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thanks!