# How can I print the body of file that user provide the filename from input

Tags: python, file

I was wondering if there is anyway that from a filename provided by an user we can get the body of the file

Here as sample of my code

```
fname = input('Enter filename...')

fileObject = open(fname, 'r')

print(fname)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: printing a file to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084260/python-printing-a-file-to-stdout)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to read the data from the file and then print it out, or do everything at once:

```
fname = input("What's the file name? ")
# this assumes it's on the same directory
with open(fname, 'r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:  (read the official Python doc. too)

```py
      with open(filename) as f:
            content = f.read()
        # you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
        
      print(content)
```

Comment: There is no need to `readlines()` if you don't want lines. You can simply `read()` instead.